# PyCharm not showing plot properly

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a test plot here, that i want to display in pycharm

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Come up with x and y
x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

# Just print x and y for fun
print(x)
print(y)

# Plot the x and y and you are supposed to see a sine curve
plt.plot(x, y)

# Without the line below, the figure won't show
plt.interactive(False)
plt.show()
```

i addded some comments for more readability..

however when i run the script, nothing is showing in the `SciView` window in pycharm. Why would that be? I looked into other resources, that set the `plt.interactive(False)` might help, but i have tried both options without any luck, can anybody help?

[image: Here is what shows when i run the script]

Comment: Having currently a similar issue. Can you add which version of Pycharm you use? Also do you execute the code manually in the console or do you run the script?

Comment: What does `matplotlib.get_backend()` return?